# How to make an ajax request with keyup event from input out side the data table?

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

I need to make an ajax call out side of the data table. I have an input which is not inside my data table. Basically i need to listen that input and on onkeyup event I want to make ajax request for my data table and feed my table with data returned ajax request.

Here is my table:

```
 var table = $('#bootstrap-data-table-export').DataTable({
                lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],                
                columnDefs: [{
                    targets: -1,
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: " <button class='btn btn-sm table-button-dark' > <i class='fa fa-archive fa-xs' ></i></button> <button class='btn table-button-dark btn-sm' > <i class='fa fa-eye fa-xs' ></i></button> <button class='btn table-button-dark btn-sm'  > <i class='fas fa-download fa-xs' /></button>"

                }],
                
                language: {
                    lengthMenu: "Sayfa Başına _MENU_ Kayıt",
                    zeroRecords: "Böyle Bir Kayıt Yok",
                    info: "_PAGE_ Sayfanın _PAGES_ . Sayfasındasınız",
                    infoEmpty: "No records available",
                    infoFiltered: "(Toplam _MAX_ Filtrelendi)",
                    search: "Ara",
                    paginate: {
                        previous: "Önceki",
                        next:"Sonraki"
                    }

                }
            });
```

Here is my ajax request:

```
function getDT(data) {
 
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                data: data,
                url: '/api/ajax/SeriesList',
            }).done(function (result) {
                console.log(typeof result);
                result = JSON.parse(result);
                $('#bootstrap-data-table-export').DataTable().clear();
                $('#bootstrap-data-table-export').DataTable().rows.add(result.data).draw();
            });
        }
```

I can change everything in this code it doesnt matter. I really need an answer.

Comment: Create a function to create a table. Use that function like ```var table = generateTable(data, and, other, arguments)``` Call the same function to regenerate the table with the new data that you recieved from Ajax.

Comment: Thank you. I just thought about that. I'm trying to implement that logic right now if I can I'm gonna share :)

Answer (score 0):

Okey I solved that issue. As @Bulent said I created a function

```
  function CustomInitTable() {
            var table = $('#bootstrap-data-table-export').DataTable({
                lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                columnDefs: [{
                    targets: -1,
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: " <button class='btn btn-sm table-button-dark' > <i class='fa fa-archive fa-xs' ></i></button> <button class='btn table-button-dark btn-sm' > <i class='fa fa-eye fa-xs' ></i></button> <button class='btn table-button-dark btn-sm'  > <i class='fas fa-download fa-xs' /></button>"

                }],
                ajax: {
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/api/ajax/IssuedInvoiceController",
                    data: RequestObject
                },
                "bDestroy": true,
                language: {
                    lengthMenu: "Sayfa Başına _MENU_ Kayıt",
                    zeroRecords: "Böyle Bir Kayıt Yok",
                    info: "_PAGE_ Sayfanın _PAGES_ . Sayfasındasınız",
                    infoEmpty: "No records available",
                    infoFiltered: "(Toplam _MAX_ Filtrelendi)",
                    search: "Ara",
                    paginate: {
                        previous: "Önceki",
                        next: "Sonraki"
                    }

                }
            });


        }
```

And then I called my CustomInitTable function from my searchRequester function.

```
function searchRequester(id) {

            RequestObject[id] = $(`#${id}`).val()
           
            CustomInitTable()
        }
```

That search requester function is bind to my html inputs onkeyup event.
I know it's probably not the best solution for this issue. If I find something better than that I'll update here.

IMPORTANT!
You have to add "bDestroy":true to your data table otherwise you initialise data table twice and that's not allowed.